# Stack Overflow Careers can't see the data

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I logged in to Stack Overflow Careers. Right now it says:

> We need more information before accelerating your matches. Add at least one complete record of work experience or education

However... I already added both. Either I missed something or there is a bug.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: You probably need to fill in more details. It _does_ say "one **complete** record".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work experience entry is a little sparse. We require at least one entry with 150 characters or more describing your responsibilities in that role.

For example, try describing projects that you worked on - that'll make you more interesting to employers and hence more likely to be contacted for positions.

The 150 characters requirement isn't very clear in the UI but we have an item in the backlog to address that so it should be fixed soon!

Comment: "Isn't very clear" is an understatement.